# How to resize xtermjs terminal

Tags: javascript, terminal, xtermjs

I don't know how to resize my xterm.js terminal. Somebody know how to do ? I tried with css but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is the [fit-addon](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/tree/master/addons/xterm-addon-fit), which can propagate container size changes to the terminal state. If you are connected to a PTY you also have to announce the size changes back to the PTY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can define your xterm base data to set cols and rows:

```
let xterm = new Xterm({
    rows: 22,
    cols: x, //any value
});
```

To do a resize, you can use `fitAddon`:

```
let fitAddon = new FitAddon();
xterm.loadAddon(fitAddon);
fitAddon.fit();

xterm.onResize(function (evt) {
   websocket.send({ rows: evt.rows });
});
```

more details about resizing `xterm.js` terminal [here](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/tree/master/addons/xterm-addon-fit).

## Update

I think changing the above code for `onResize` prop to this one bellow and adding `xterm_resize_ob` will improve the resize functionality:

```
xterm.onResize(function (evt) {
  const terminal_size = {
    Width: evt.cols,
    Height: evt.rows,
  };
  websocket.send("\x04" + JSON.stringify(terminal_size));
});

const xterm_resize_ob = new ResizeObserver(function (entries) {
  // since we are observing only a single element, so we access the first element in entries array
  try {
    fitAddon && fitAddon.fit();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

// start observing for resize
xterm_resize_ob.observe(document.querySelector("#xterm"));
```